# rsyslog upgrade fails: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: debian, apt, rsyslog

I'm having trouble upgrading rsyslog on a Debian server.

```
root@trip:/home# apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up rsyslog (8.4.2-1+deb8u2) ...
Job for rsyslog.service failed. See 'systemctl status rsyslog.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript rsyslog, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package rsyslog (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rsyslog
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Output of `systemctl status rsyslog.service`:

```
â rsyslog.service - System Logging Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rsyslog.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Mon 2016-01-25 09:54:17 CET; 3min 43s ago
     Docs: man:rsyslogd(8)
           http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/
  Process: 27385 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 27385 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 25 09:54:16 trip systemd[1]: Failed to start System Logging Service.
Jan 25 09:54:16 trip systemd[1]: Unit rsyslog.service entered failed state.
Jan 25 09:54:17 trip systemd[1]: rsyslog.service start request repeated too quickly, refusing to start.
Jan 25 09:54:17 trip systemd[1]: Failed to start System Logging Service.
Jan 25 09:54:17 trip systemd[1]: Unit rsyslog.service entered failed state.
Jan 25 09:54:17 trip systemd[1]: rsyslog.service start request repeated too quickly, refusing to start.
Jan 25 09:54:17 trip systemd[1]: Failed to start System Logging Service.
```

Output of `journalctl -xn`:

```
-- Logs begin at Sun 2016-01-24 18:29:42 CET, end at Mon 2016-01-25 09:54:17 CET. --
Jan 25 09:54:16 trip systemd[1]: Unit rsyslog.service entered failed state.
Jan 25 09:54:16 trip systemd[1]: rsyslog.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 25 09:54:16 trip systemd[1]: Failed to start System Logging Service.
-- Subject: Unit rsyslog.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit rsyslog.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Jan 25 09:54:16 trip systemd[1]: Unit rsyslog.service entered failed state.
Jan 25 09:54:17 trip systemd[1]: rsyslog.service start request repeated too quickly, refusing to start.
Jan 25 09:54:17 trip systemd[1]: Failed to start System Logging Service.
-- Subject: Unit rsyslog.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit rsyslog.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Jan 25 09:54:17 trip systemd[1]: Unit rsyslog.service entered failed state.
Jan 25 09:54:17 trip systemd[1]: rsyslog.service start request repeated too quickly, refusing to start.
Jan 25 09:54:17 trip systemd[1]: Failed to start System Logging Service.
-- Subject: Unit rsyslog.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit rsyslog.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Jan 25 09:54:17 trip systemd[1]: Unit syslog.socket entered failed state.
```

I've removed rsyslog and then tried to reinstall it, but that didn't help. And `apt-get -f install` throws the same error as `apt-get upgrade`. So now I seem to be stuck with a half-configured rsyslog. How can I fix this?

Edit: the output of `systemctl status syslog.service`:

```
â rsyslog.service - System Logging Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rsyslog.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Mon 2016-01-25 11:14:36 CET; 3min 49s ago
     Docs: man:rsyslogd(8)
           http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/
  Process: 31319 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 31319 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 25 11:14:36 trip systemd[1]: Failed to start System Logging Service.
Jan 25 11:14:36 trip systemd[1]: Unit rsyslog.service entered failed state.
Jan 25 11:14:36 trip systemd[1]: rsyslog.service start request repeated too quickly, refusing to start.
Jan 25 11:14:36 trip systemd[1]: Failed to start System Logging Service.
Jan 25 11:14:36 trip systemd[1]: Unit rsyslog.service entered failed state.
Jan 25 11:14:36 trip systemd[1]: rsyslog.service start request repeated too quickly, refusing to start.
Jan 25 11:14:36 trip systemd[1]: Failed to start System Logging Service.
```

Comment: Could you show the output of `systemctl status syslog.service`?

Comment: @RonaldPK, give it a try: `apt-get -f install`

Comment: I've updated the question with answers to gf_ and bangal. `apt-get -f install` throws the same error.

Comment: Could you do: `systemctl disable syslog.service`, `systemctl enable syslog.service`, `systemctl restart syslog.service`, `systemctl restart rsyslog.service`. After this, check if `rsyslog.service` now works.

Comment: `systemctl enable syslog.service` says `Failed to execute operation: No such file or directory`. The restart commands both say `Job for rsyslog.service failed. See 'systemctl status rsyslog.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.`

Comment: Could you do `systemctl disable rsyslog.service`, `systemctl enable rsyslog.service`, `systemctl restart rsyslog.service` and check if it's running. Also: Please ping me, via @gf_ for example, otherwise I won't be notified.

Comment: Today I had the same problem like yours @RonaldPK . I fixed by `ps axu|grep rsyslog` - I saw that I had already running rsyslog, so I kill it and do `apt-get -f install` and all went fine.

Comment: Thank you @NikolayNikolov , you saved my day! All is fine now, at last.

Comment: Also thanks to @gf_ for your answers. disable/enable/restart ended with the same message `Job for rsyslog.service failed.`

Comment: Which Debian version is this? Which upgrade path did you do / choose? It would be good to track this and submit a bug report, if there isn't one already. This would be a nice thing to do to prevent this same thing for other people in the future. I could take care of the report, if you could provide these information.

Comment: @gf_ Debian 8.3, now. I suppose I ran this upgrade from 8.2 https://www.debian.org/News/2016/20160123 when I ran `apt-get upgrade` yesterday. A quick search in Debian's bug system doesn't show any similar problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Today I had the same problem like yours @RonaldPK . I fixed by `ps axu|grep rsyslog` - I saw that I had already running `rsyslog`, so I kill it and do `apt-get -f install` and all went fine.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

**Stop the rsyslog first**

```
 sudo service rsyslog stop
 sudo systemctl stop rsyslog.service
 sudo systemctl disable rsyslog.service
```

**Then Try:**

```
 sudo apt-get -f install
```